# Inverse property naming (ORM scenario)

Tags: c#, naming, entity-framework, orm

I have a class that represents a process. In this process there are inputs boxes and output boxes.

```
public class Process
{
    public long ProcessId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Box> InputBoxes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Box> OutputBoxes { get; set; }
}
```

As you know, naming things is one of the hardest things in programming, and in this scenario, I don't know what name I can give to the inverse property:

```
public class Box
{
    public long BoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Process ProcessWhereBoxIsInput { get; set; }    /* ugly name */
    public virtual Process ProcessWhereBoxIsOutput { get; set; }   /* ugly name */
}
```

What is the common way of naming things in scenarios like this?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule I use quite often is to remove the plural and the subject from the original property name, then add "to". In your example, I would probably end up with:

```
public class Box
{
    public long BoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Process InputTo { get; set; }    /* ugly name */
    public virtual Process OutputTo { get; set; }   /* ugly name */
}
```

Depending how I plan to use the property (i.e. whether it makes sense grammatically), I might add the obverse entity name back on to the end.

```
public class Box
{
    public long BoxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Process InputToProcess { get; set; }    /* ugly name */
    public virtual Process OutputToProcess { get; set; }   /* ugly name */
}
```

Comment: It did instantly sense to me. Accepted!